# Can I reduce "couldn't find anything" to "nothing" in this sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction, negation, coordination

Can I write

> I checked it, but nothing

instead of

> I checked it but couldn't find anything

?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*"But nothing"* is too incomplete to be an independent clause, so *"I checked it, but nothing"* would not be a well formed sentence.

Very informally, one might possibly say:

> I checked.  Nothin'.

… but I would recommend against it for an English learner.

What could be an acceptable sentence would be:

> I checked it, but found nothing.

Answer (score 6):

It depends on the context.  "I checked it, but nothing" is colloquial or informal.  It is not formal.

For example, you would not say that as a doctor talking to a patient.  I would not use it in any professional context.

Answer (score 2):

> I checked it, but nothing.

This not a sentence, even in the most radical of grammars. However, it would certainly be seen in reported speech, in journalism or fiction. There, it might be taken to mean:

> I checked it, but nothing *(was there/was happening/had happened/was new/&c.)*

Your proposed replacement sentence is grammatical, but would be improved by the addition of a comma:

> I checked it, but couldn't find anything.